# Use d3.js in vue

Tags: vue.js, d3.js, element-ui

I insert my own component used d3 into element-ui el-table-column template,but this can not work,the svg element is empty.I am new in d3 and I can not figrue out it by myself.I am very confused,please give me some suggestions,thank you!
the result
[image: the empty svg element without g element fill with rect element]
[image: the right result I draw with an Html not vue]

Here is my code, a d3 component and a vue template  , I use d3 v4 and element-ui

```
<template>
    <!-- 智能检索表格基因区域图 -->
    <div>
        <svg width="180" height="40"></svg>
    </div>
</template>
    
<script>
    import * as d3 from 'd3'
    
    export default {
        props: {
            startPosition: Number,
            endPosition: Number,
        },
        computed: {
            positionArr() {
                return [this.startPosition, this.endPosition]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            drawSVG() {
            // 定义画布宽度
            // const containerWidth = 180;
            // 矩形高度
            const rectHeight = 6;
            // 默认矩形的位置
    
    
            // 数据源  图上绿色部分
            let dataSet = [
                [790, 2292],
                [5041, 5619],
                [8379, 8469],
                [8797, 9417],
                [1, 634],
                [6062, 6310],
                [8379, 8653],
                [9086, 9719],
                [2085, 5096],
                [5559, 5850],
                [6225, 8795],
            ];
            // push 序列起点位置和终点位置数组
            dataSet.push(this.positionArr);
        
            //定义一个线性比例尺，domain为定义域，range为值域
            const scaleLinear = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([1, 9719])
                .range([0, 180]);
        
            // 选择画布
            let svg = d3.select("svg");
            console.log('svg', svg);
            // 为画布添加一个g标签，并为其设置transform属性
            let g = svg.append("g")
            //   .attr("transform","translate("+marge.top+","+marge.left+")");
            // 在g标签中绘制矩形
            g.selectAll("rect")
                .data(dataSet)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", function(d) {  // x是rect起点的x坐标
                return scaleLinear(d[0]);
                })
                .attr("y",function(d,i){  // y是rect起点的y坐标
                if (i <= 3) {
                    return 0;
                } else if (i <= 7 && i > 3) {
                    return 10;
                } else if (i<= 10 && i > 7) {
                    return 20;
                } else {
                    return 0;  // 黄色矩形
                }
                })
                .attr("width",function(d, i){
                console.log('d', d);
                console.log('i', i);
                return scaleLinear(d[1]) - scaleLinear(d[0]);//设置宽,并在这里使用比例尺
                })
                .attr("height",function(d, i) {
                if (i < dataSet.length - 1) {
                    return rectHeight;
                } else {
                    return 26;
                }
                })  // rect的高度
                .attr("fill",function(d, i) {
                if (i < dataSet.length - 1) {
                    return 'green';
                } else {
                    return 'yellow';
                }
                })  // rect的填充颜色
                .attr("opacity", function(d, i) {
                if (i < dataSet.length - 1) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 0.5;
                }
                });
            },
        },
        created() {
            console.log('this.positionArr', this.positionArr);
            this.drawSVG();
        }
    }
</script>

<el-table-column label="基因区域" align="center" width="200">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
            <!-- 基因区域图组件 -->
            <!-- 绑定基因片段起始位置和终止位置 -->
            <GeneRegionGraph
            :startPosition=scope.row.partstart
            :endPosition=scope.row.partend>
            </GeneRegionGraph>
        </template>
 </el-table-column>
```

Comment: `let svg = d3.select("svg");` probably wouldn't work, would it? I think you need to use `$ref` to get the svg

Comment: Could you please show me more details?Thank you!

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html
like this, I suspect d3.select would not get the right svg dom, and to do that in vue.js is by using $ref.

Answer (score 1):

bind id attr to svg element dynamically and call drawSVG() function in mounted lifecycle instead of in created lifecycle can solve it.